# Adding entries to fstab results in emergency mode

Tags: ssh, fstab, elementary-os, sshfs, distributed-filesystem

This is my local system configuration.

```
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.0 Juno"
```

I am mounting my remote server's file system on a subdirectory by this command, which is working fine.

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other della@108.49.38.08: /mnt/Production_server
```

The terminal prompts for the local's sudo password first, then the remote's password. (Even though I have already copied the local's ed25519 public key into the remote's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, somehow that does not work. I would like to make it work, but that is more like a side question.)

Some tutorials led me to believe that I do not have to issue the above command every-time and the remote can be mounted automatically at each boot up. Following that, I entered the following line at the end of my `/etc/fstab` file.

```
sshfs#della@108.49.38.08: /mnt/Production_server
```

After I poweroff, the laptop simply refuses to boot and throws a message saying *You are in emergency mode.* Lucky that it allows me into a very basic login shell where I can edit the `/etc/fstab` using nano. Only after I eliminate the last line it boots up properly.

So basically

1. Is it possible to automatically mount the remote at each reboot? How will the authentication take place?
2. If possible, am I editing the file system table incorrectly? What should the last line look like? Or is the method entirely different?

Comment: Does this help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519613/how-to-make-an-fstab-entry-for-sshfs-on-non-standard-ssh-port-and-using-ssh-key

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Stephen Boston given link will help, just to gives more background.

1. Never give remote mount point without **_netdev** reason is you can't mount with network, so first network come up and then try to mount it.
2. Since you are giving in fstab and remote mount is not available system will refuse to mount it you can try to use **nofail** only if filesystem supports.